# How to get clean email content from server into the database

Tags: php, mysql, email

I'm fetching any new received emails sent to a certain address and saving them into my database using the following script.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
// Config
date_default_timezone_get('Africa/Nairobi');
$dbuser = "USERNAME";
$dbpass = "PASSWORD";
$dbname = "DATABASE";
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$notify= 'user@example.com'; // an email address required in case of errors

// read from stdin
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = "";
while (!feof($fd)) {
    $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);
// handle email
$lines = explode("\n", $email);

// empty vars
$from = "";
$subject = "";
$headers = "";
$message = "";
$splittingheaders = true;
for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    if ($splittingheaders) {
        // this is a header
        $headers .= $lines[$i]."\n";

        // look out for special headers
        if (preg_match("/^Subject: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $subject = $matches[1];
        }
        if (preg_match("/^From: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $from = $matches[1];
        }
        if (preg_match("/^To: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $to = $matches[1];
        }
    } else {
        // not a header, but message
        $message .= $lines[$i]."\n";
    }

    if (trim($lines[$i])=="") {
        // empty line, header section has ended
        $splittingheaders = false;
    }
}

if ($conn = @mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass)) {
  if(!@mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn))
    mail($email,'Email Logger Error',"There was an error selecting the email logger database.\n\n".mysql_error());
  $from    = mysql_real_escape_string($from);
  $to    = mysql_real_escape_string($to);
  $subject = mysql_real_escape_string($subject);
  $headers = mysql_real_escape_string($headers);
  $message = mysql_real_escape_string($message);

  /*$string = explode("UTF-8", $message);

    $string = $string[2];

    $string = explode("--", $string);

    $message = $string[0];*/

  $email   = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
  $result = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO email_log (`to`,`from`,`subject`,`headers`,`message`,`source`) VALUES('$to','$from','$subject','$headers','$message','$email')");
  if (mysql_affected_rows() == 0)
    mail($notify,'Email Logger Error',"There was an error inserting into the email logger database.\n\n".mysql_error());
} else {
  mail($notify,'Email Logger Error',"There was an error connecting the email logger database.\n\n".mysql_error());
}
?>
```

But I have one problem. The body section save lots of unnecesary content into my database.

For example, I send the words 'Hello World', I get the following results

```
--001a113f9a3abed08b051116a161
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

Hello World

--001a113f9a3abed08b051116a161
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<div dir="ltr">Hello World</div>

--001a113f9a3abed08b051116a161--
```

How can I filter the other content and remain only with "Hello World", or is there a better PHP script to pipe emails?

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a multipart mime message, which may contain further parts such as attachments. You'd normally split it up in parts and parse each part according to it's content-type and encoding. You can then typically use the first text/plain part as the plain-text message, or if the mail didn't include a text/plain part you can use the first text/html part from which you strip the HTML tags.

Unfortunately I don't have code lying around to do this from scratch (since you're reading from stdin), but if you feel like fetching mails directly from PHP using IMAP/POP3, this piece of code has been working well for me for a while: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php#85486. You might be able to adapt it to your needs, if you can replace the `fetchstructure` functionality that breaks up the message into parts.